# Why does the new action in the controller need the instance variable initialized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

Why does the new action in the controller need the instance variable @article initialized? I have tested that a record gets saved well to the tables in the database without the instance variable in the new action.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what do you mean with "the instance variable is needed to be initialized" ?

Comment: remove it if you don't need it ?. How can you check if you need it or not ?, just go to the `new.html.erb` template in the `articles` folder and see it's there. It could be possible that in your `new.html.erb` template you're initializing a new instance of `Article`, that's one of the reasons you don't need that variable.

Comment: If you want to make use of form helpers you need it or else you can skip the initialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of creating the empty instance of your model is based around the idea that your new view shares a lot of view code with your edit view, and thus needs the model to work on.

For example, in many cases, the new and edit page are nearly identical. The new page for your article may allow the user to enter in a name, an author, and a publishing date. Now the user may wish to edit this information, and you will probably show them the exact same three text fields for editing the name, author, and publishing date.

To DRY this up (Don't Repeat Yourself), you may combine that form in to a single view partial. You would end up with views like this:

```
# new.html.haml
New Article
= render :partial => "form"

# edit.html.haml
Edit Article
= render :partial => "form"

# _form.html.haml
= text_field_tag "title", @article.title
= text_field_tag "author", @article.author
= text_field_tag "publishing_date", @article.publishing_date
```

Obviously when you are editing an existing article, you need to fetch that data from your database, and then use its properties to fill out the form. What a lot of people do is reuse that form with their new page, but now the form is expecting to have an `@article` variable, so programmers initialize an empty one in their `new` action.

This also helps if your form partial requires calling methods on your object. For example:

```
# article.rb
def published_today?
  return (self.publishing_date.to_date == Date.today)
end

# _form.html.haml
- if @article.published_today?
  %strong New!
```

But if your new and edit pages don't share the same code, and your new page doesn't need an empty model instance created, then don't bother, that's okay.

Comment: Great explanation! I came to see form partial is related to this.